# Extension of user model in django redux registration gives NotImplementedError at /accounts/register/ error

Tags: python, django, redux, django-registration

I am trying to extend the user model in django redux registration. I have tried some possible solutions, but all in vain.

Django Debug shows that is "NotImplementedError at /accounts/register/
No exception message supplied"

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741212/django-registration-redux-with-custom-user-model-registration-notimplementederro) to solve this problem 
Moreover, i was following rvlsico answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620940/django-registration-redux-add-extra-field) on how to get started on it.

Any help would be appreciated. Here are my code snippets:
regbackend.py

```
    class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
        form_class = ProfileForm
        def register(self,form_class):
            new_user = super(MyRegistrationView, self).register(form_class)
            p = form_class.cleaned_data['teacher']
            new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, teacher=p)
            new_profile.save()
            return new_user
```

models.py

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
        teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

        @property
        def is_teacher(self):
             return self.teacher
```

forms.py

```
    class ProfileForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
        teacher = forms.BooleanField(required=False,label=("Are you a teacher?"))
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    path('', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),]
```